# Create Dictionary from Text FIle

Tags: python, file, dictionary

How could I create a dictionary from a text file? I don't want anything special in the text file itself because I would like to write directly to the file from Python.

Text file:

```
Soda $2 Burger $5 Shake $4 Fries $3
```

Code:

```
file = 'file.dat'
filer = open(file, "r")
food = {}
for i in filer:
    x = i.split(" ")
    for i in range(len(x)):
        if i %2 == 0:
            a = x[i]
        else:
            b = x[i]
        food[a] = b
```

Comment: Oh shoot it works!

Comment: Does the file have to be formatted like that?

Comment: Preferably, yes. But I can change it. I just wanted it simple because I would later write to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Oh shoot it works!

No, it shouldn't.  It should give you a "NameError: name 'b' is not defined" message.  If 'a' is set, then 'b' is either unset or left over from the previous interation when `food[a] = [b]` happens.  A more pythonic way to approach this might be:

```
file_name = 'file.dat'

food = {}

with open(file_name) as file:
    for line in file:
        pairs = line.split()
        food.update(zip(pairs[0::2], pairs[1::2]))
```

**PRODUCES**

```
{'Shake': '$4', 'Fries': '$3', 'Soda': '$2', 'Burger': '$5'}
```

Comment: Thanks! What does the 'with' statement do? And what does `zip` do? And `pairs`? And the `::`? Please explain your answer. I am a python noob.

Comment: @Indigo2003, the `with` statement is an OOP operator that invokes the object's (file's) cleanup code -- i.e. it calls `close()` on the file when the block is exited so we don't have to remember to do so.  `pairs` is simply the name of my variable and is arbitrary.  `zip()` takes two lists and interlaces them, like a clothes zipper. The `[x::y]` notation is a slice where `pairs[0::2]` are the even elements and `pairs[1::2]` are the odd elements.

Comment: what does the 2 colons mean though? and when i made 2 lists `list1 = [1, 2] list2 = ['a', 'b'] print(zip(list1, list2))` It said <zip object at 0x02DE2828>

Answer (score 0):

If you control the format, you should just use json

```
import json

d = {'Shake': '$4', 'Fries': '$3', 'Soda': '$2', 'Burger': '$5'}
with open('file.dat', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(d, f)

with open('file.dat', 'r') as f:
    print json.load(f)
```

Comment: What is `with` and `as` and `load`

Comment: `with` and `as` is the syntax for *context managers*. It is the preferred way of opening files to ensure they are closed correctly.  `json.load` and `json.dump` will read and save python objects (e.g. lists, dicts) to a file as json.  It's documented [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html#json.load).